# Unable to load dll libglorycolx2010.dll. The application has failed to start because its side by side configuration is incorrect. HRESULT: 0x800736B1

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllimport

I am using a third party dll, `libglorycolx2010.dll` in my C++ project. When i try to run the project i get the above error.

Many sources online suggested that i install Microsoft Visual C++ Distributable package which i have done. The problem is, i am not sure which dependencies are required by the dll. In that case i installed all versions Microsoft Visual C++ Distributable packages (2005,2008,2010,2012) X86 bit, but the problem still persists. I am using DllImport to load the library and i am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

I also tried to register the dll using regsvr32 but still got the same exact error. Kindly someone help.

Comment: Very hard to identify the problem. This is a generic error and there are countless causes. I suggest you contact the developer of the DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dumpbin` command using visual studio command prompt to analyze the `libglorycolx2010.dll`. This will analyze the dll and display all the dependencies of the dll.

Go to system32 folder and search for all the dependencies that were displayed using the dumpbin command.

There is a likelihood some may be missing. Go to https://www.dll-files.com/ and search for the missing dll and download it, then copy it to system32 folder.

Try running the Project again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get this error, it means that I am trying to load a 32bit dll into a 64bit application, or a 64bit dll into a 32bit application.

Comment: I tried that. Initially my machine was x64 and i was getting the same exact error. i had to downgrade to x86 but still got the same error. Even when normally registering the dll using regsvr32.

Comment: It's not the machine. It's the project settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: Please advice, how do i check and change that? I am using Visual Studio 2012 Proffessional

Comment: No, bitness mismatch gives a different error, `BadImageFormatException`

Comment: How to consume libgorycolx2010 in android? to operate the cdm using android phone? @Shloim